# Undefined reference and linking libraries

Tags: c

I'm experiencing some compilation issues with my dynamic library. It should be linked to main.c but for all references to it I receive "undefined reference to function_name".

The contents of main.c isn't really that important; I include my library:

```
#include "matrix.h"
```

Then I have a simple Makefile to link the two.

```
#Variables
LIB = matrix

# Usual compilation flags
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -g
CPPFLAGS = -I../include -DDEBUG
LDFLAGS = -lm 

# Special rules and targets
.PHONY: all clean help

all: $(LIB).o libmatrix.so main

$(LIB).o: $(LIB).c $(LIB).h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -fPIC -c -o $@ $<

libmatrix.so: $(LIB).o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -shared -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS)

main: main.o libmatrix.so
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< -L -lmatrix
```

Can anyone direct me to where I might be going wrong? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the compilation error results.

Comment: ... including the actual commands emitted by the `make` run (which should be echoed to the terminal).

Answer (score 4):

You probably want `-L.` not `-L` in your last line, so:

```
main: main.o libmatrix.so
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< -L. -lmatrix
```

You should read [Program Library HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) and [Drepper's paper: *How to Write Shared Libraries*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf); you might want to set some `-rpath` at link time (maybe using `-Wl,-rpath,.` ...), and you might want to link with `-rdynamic` ....

Alternatively, set your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to contain `.` (I don't recommend that), or install your shared library in `/usr/local/lib/` (and add it to `/etc/ld.so.conf` then run `ldconfig`). See also [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html), [ld.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), [ldconfig(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html)

Comment: This wasn't working before but now somehow is. Anyway, I now have an error "./main: error while loading shared libraries: libmatrix.so cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"